# Send a special parameter via RequestBuilder POST on GWT

Tags: gwt, post, parameters, request, special-characters

I am a beginner of GWT.

In my application, i need to post parameter which of value is a URL such like a following string.

'http://h.com/a.php?code=186&cate_code=MV&album=acce'

As you can see it, it includes character sequences '&cat_code='.

As i know, &parametername=value is form of one parameter!...

Because of this, a PHP file on my server side, only receives a following string,

'http://hyangmusic.com/Ticket_View.php?code=186'

How could i do in this situation... i want to receive a full URL as parameter on the server side PHP.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

---

my code.

```
String name = "John";
String url = "http://h.com/a.php?code=186&cate_code=MV&album=acce";
String parameter = "name="+name+"&url="+url;
        builder.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        builder.sendRequest(parameter,
                new RequestCallback() {
                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`URL.encodeQueryString(url)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encodeQueryString%28java.lang.String%29) so that your `&` is turned into a `%26` (26 being the hexadecimal representation of the UTF-8 encoding of &)

Comment: Thank you! It solved :), actually I was trying to use the function Url.encode(), but it was not working properly. But the fucntion URL.encodeQueryString() works nicely.